# java regex matcher error

Tags: java, regex, error-handling

I am trying to find the regex of the following link `http://anythingbutrbitrary.blogspot.in/search?updated-max=2014-02-10T11:58:00-08:00&max-results=1`.

My code with regex `http://anythingbutrbitrary.blogspot.in/search?updated-max=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}&max-results=\\d{1}` returning false. What is wrong with the regex? My java code is as follows:

```
String regex= "http://anythingbutrbitrary.blogspot.in/search?updated-max=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}&max-results=\\d{1}";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(regex));
Matcher m = p.matcher("http://anythingbutrbitrary.blogspot.in/search?updated-max=2014-02-10T11:58:00-08:00&max-results=1");
System.out.println(m.lookingAt());
```

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of mistakes in your regex.

1. You are calling `Pattern.quote` which will make your regex literal.
2. Meta characters like dot and `?` need to be escaped to `\\.` and `\\?`

**EDIT:** After looking at your regex I found that is also wrong. Use this regex:

```
String regex="http://anythingbutrbitrary\\.blogspot\\.in/search\\?updated-max=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}-\\d{2}:\\d{2}&max-results=\\d";
```

Comment: You also need to escape the backslash `\/`

Comment: No that is not needed in Java.

Answer (score 1):

`Pattern.quote()` may not do what you want it to do...

From the [online API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> This method produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern that would match the string s as if it were a literal pattern.
>
> Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.

In addition, the `lookingAt()` javadoc says (emphasis mine):

> Returns: `true` if, and only if, **a prefix** of the input sequence matches this matcher's pattern

Few minor mistakes in your regex, surrounded by two stars:

```
http://anythingbutrbitrary**.**blogspot**.**in/search**?**updated-max=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-**d{2}**T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}-\\d{2}**-**\\d{2}&max-results=\\d{1}
```

1. Should escape period (otherwise you'll match *any* character. Doesn't really matter for this specific case, though)
2. Same as 1.
3. Escape the question mark (it means "one or none of the preceding character", which certainly won't produce correct results)
4. Forgot to escape `d` (should be `\\d`)
5. dash instead of colon

You should make your pattern code by doing `Pattern.compile(regex);`. Right now, you're making a pattern that matches `regex` *as is*, with escapes and metacharacters ignored. In addition, I think you might want `m.matches()` rather than `m.lookingAt()`...

Comment: I thought that's what I said? Was I not clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

- escape the `?` with a backslash, otherwise it means "1 or 0 of previous term", so you're losing a character, which is why it's not matching (technically you should escape the dots too, but hardly worth it)
- use String.matches() instead - it's easier to use

Try this:

```
String regex = "http://anythingbutrbitrary.blogspot.in/search\\?updated-max=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}&max-results=\\d";
if (urlStr.matches(regex))
```